# Live Statistics / incrementer  via Timestamp

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, loops, time

I have a strange problem and I wasn't sure how to word the title.

**What I'm Trying To Do:**

I want to keep track of a running total and I want this running total to update live to my page every second. I'm not trying to track visitors, it's going to track something weird like "amount of blood cells in your body right now!" Here is a website that does what I want to do, but they do it in jquery, I'm trying to do it in JS to keep the JS files to a minimum. http://www.usagain.com/   (left side)

**How I'm Doing It:**

I have a JS file with AJAX that is linked to a PHP file and that PHP file opens a Text file -> grabs a number -> increments it by 1 -> sends said number back to the JS -> Updates the number to HTML -> and the PHP updates the text file -> close txt file.

**My Problem:**

The counter works, it increments but the problem is if I have 2 browsers running the same page the number will increment by 2. If I have 3 browsers; the number will increment by 3 and so on. I think it has something to do with the writing to the file but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**My Code**

HTML/CSS/Javascript/AJAX

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter</title>
<script language="javascript" src="../jquery1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addCommas(nStr) //http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html -- Source
    {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }

    function getNum()
    {
        $.post('test.php', function(data){
            $('#counter').html(addCommas(data));
        })
    }   
    setTimeOut(getNum, 1000);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #counterContainer{color: #52504D;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;position:relative;top:22px;}
    #counter{color: #1E7EC8; font-size: 25px;letter-spacing:1px;}
</style> 
</head>
<body onload="getNum()">
    <div id="counterContainer">
        <div id="counter"><!--Counter Goes Here, Do Not Disturb--></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP File

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen("staticNum.txt", "r+");
    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    $num = fgets($fp, 11);
    $num = intval($num)+1;

    echo $num;

    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fputs($fp, "$num");
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

My Text File just has this number in it:

`10000100260`

Any suggestions would be great. My first thought was a database but then I figured I'd have the same problem. I do want to stay away from Session variables and Cookies though for sure since I don't think they're necessary. I could be wrong though.

Bonus points if you can figure out a way to solve my problem without a database! (Not really though im not an admin :(

Comment: +1 for nicely laid out description

Comment: If what you're keeping a running total of, is visitors (if not ignore the rest and just let me know what you're tracking!), it is no doubt best to use sessions. Otherwise a page change or refresh would result in a false increase in your visitor count.

Comment: I'm not tracking visitors :(   that's all i get on google searches too I will edit my question to specify. Check again under "What I'm Doing" in like 2 seconds. **I really need a better title :/ **

Comment: Right, so you want a number in the background to update on a per second basis, unaffected by the amount of times the site is visited per second? In which case you could set up a CRON job on the web server to just run the php file every second (possibly). My next best thought is to make use of the unix timestamp!

Comment: I am absolutely not server savvy. Also being at a small company we just have a hand-full of developers :S   is there a way I can achieve this in code?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP -- I second using timestamps as a reference. The reliability is highest.

Comment: How does that work? Do I need to collect a value via PHP and echo it out or does that server do it for me? I'm confused on the process of how a timestamp or cron job will help (server illiterate), but i'll do some research

Comment: @SmokeyPHP is a cron job resource heavy? If I have a cron job running every second then will that bog down the server?

Comment: Now you've mentioned it, I don't think I've seen a cron service support intervals of much less than a minute. I'm going to take a copy of the html you posted and try to implement my idea, let me know if you get joy before I get back to you.

Comment: Yeah I looked into it and my Cron Jobs only go to increments of 3 minutes at the lowest :(    I seriously cannot imagine how that website is doing it.

Comment: You could change your PHP to (instead of the intval+1 line) say $num=$num+(time()-1325894350);
This means that no matter how many javascript calls from however many browsers, the increment will stay steady.

Comment: Ok why is it time minus that number specifically? I'd have to play around with numbers to get it to only increment by one cause with that line of code it is incrementing by alot each second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting, try with timestamp:

```
value = ( timestamp % ((max_limit - min_limit) / 1.5 ) ) * 1.5 + min_limit
```

Comment: You sir are amazing! The only problem is that I have to play around with numbers to find an exact number to start at.

Comment: To start at the number you want, add a modifier to timestamp: value = ( (timestamp + modifier) % ((max_limit - min_limit) / 1.5 ) ) * 1.5 + min_limit

Comment: I tried adding a modifier but it made no difference. The hardest part is calculating a good `$min` and `$max` so that it starts at a certain number. timestamps are hard :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how your counter is going to work - where it's counting from etc, but I think this should help you:

```
var init_count = 10000100260; //starting heartbeats
var count_start = 1325803921; //timestamp of when initial count was taken

function update_count()
{
    var utstamp = new Date();
    utstamp = Math.round(utstamp.getTime()/1000); //get current unix timestamp
    var newcount = (utstamp - count_start) + init_count; //add seconds passed since initial count, to the initial count
    $("#beat_count").html(newcount); //set the contents of your element to the new number
}

var ticker = setInterval(update_count,1000); //call the above function every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
```

You can get your initial timestamp by using the form here: http://www.functions-online.com/mktime.html

This could raise more questions than it answers, but let me know either way!

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem with Javascript is that I have to keep track of the number. The only time it should reset back to 1,000,000,000 is when it hits 9,999,999,999. It gets its initial number from the number I set in the txt file. PHP pulls the contents of the text file up to the 10th byte, converts to int on PHP line4 and adds 1. Then overwrites the text file. I was thinking about a javascript "count up to this date" script but those tend to be long. I'll have to play around with that later. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 0):

> The counter works, it increments but the problem is if I have 2 browsers running the same page the number will increment by 2. If I have 3 browsers; the number will increment by 3 and so on. I think it has something to do with the writing to the file but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I assume you're having multiple browsers running per user. The counter works, but what you think is a user is infact a browser. As every browser will trigger the increase of the count, what you describe is not a problem but just the fact how your script works.

Comment: Right. Users and browsers are the same thing in this case since the event is triggered automatically on load and thereafter every second. The question is how can I modify my script so that it doesn't do this.